# How to check timestamp and prefix name in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to delete the last recent record from my table
by checking the timestamp and the prefix Nom

For example in my table the last record is :

```
Id   Nom          CDate
115  PL-TT-AA-12  10-06-1 10:35:10,308223000
```

And MyTable,

```
Id   Nom          CDate                       NameID
115  PL-TT-AA-12  10-06-1 10:35:10,308223000  100
115  PL-TT-AA-25  10-06-1 10:30:21,308223000  100 
115  PL-TT-AA-98  10-06-4 10:30:21,308223000  100
115  PL-TT-AA-56  10-06-5 10:30:21,308223000  100
```

I can do this:

```
DELETE from MyTable
WHERE id = 
    (SELECT id FROM
        (SELECT id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY CDate desc) AS rn 
         FROM MyTable 
         WHERE NameID = 35)
     WHERE rn = 1);
```

It works but I want to check Nom by prefix and timestamp and then delete the record which is between the timestamp; it is safer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean; why is that record the newest (what format is that timestamp in, YY-MM-D?)? What are you checking `nom` against, and what do you mean by deleting between the timestamps?

Comment: May be the uniqueness goes with `timestamp` + `nom` ?

Comment: You might select the latest one by it's ORA_ROWSCN.

Comment: What i want to do is to select the Nom by prefix like 'PL-TT-AA%', save it in variable and then find the recent record in date and time  and then delete it